# All finite groups $G$ which have $|G|-1$ cyclic subgroups and $|G$| is not divisible by $4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Find all finite groups $G$ which have the properties:
>   (i) $|G|$ is not divisible by $4$;
>   (ii) $G$ has exactly $|G|-1$ cyclic subgroups.

I observed that $\mathbb{Z_3}$ works and I also figured out that if $|G|>3$, then $G$ cannot be cyclic because it wouldn't satisfy (ii).
I also noticed tried considering the cyclic subgroups generated by each element, hoping to obtain something related to (ii), but I wasn't successful.

Answer (score 7):

[Tarnauceanu](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=2ahUKEwiqoYiFjJrnAhUsuqQKHT5sChkQFjAGegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ias.ac.in%2Farticle%2Ffulltext%2Fpmsc%2F129%2F04%2F0052&usg=AOvVaw0cgnueGMCRtkQ-UicmyTd2) proved in $2015$ that a
finite group $G$ has $|G| − 1$ cyclic subgroups if and only if $G$ is either $C_3,C_4, S_3$ or $D_8$. [Here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/272845620_Finite_Groups_With_a_Certain_Number_of_Cyclic_Subgroups) is the proof, which is half of a page.

Perhaps it is interesting to note the following open problem. Let $c(G)$ denote the set of all cyclic subgroups of $G$.

**Open Problem**: Describe the finite groups $G$ satisfying $|c(G)| = |G| − r$ , where $2 ≤ r ≤ |G| − 1$.

Comment: Thank you for the general result ! Is there an easier way to solve this by using (i)? We can obviously go for the proof in the article you linked, but I suppose that there should be an easier way by using (i) since I encountered this problem in a book for high school students from my country .

Comment: The proof given there is very short. I added it to my answer. It is only half a page.

Comment: I read that proof and the only part I cannot understand is why $\sum_{i=1}^k n_i \phi(d_i)=n$.

Comment: The open problem as stated seems to be asking to classify all finite groups. I suppose it is more interesting to looking at $r$ small or $r$ large. For example it is easy to see that $r = |G| - 1$ if and only if $G$ is trivial, and $r = |G| - 2$ if and only if $G$ is cyclic of prime order.

Comment: @user69503: This is because in a cyclic group of order $d_i$, the number of generators is $\phi(d_i)$.

Answer (score 6):

To have $|G|-1$ cyclic subgroups, every element of $G$ except one of them must generate a unique subgroup. There will be two elements $a\neq b$ that generate the same subgroup.

So except for $a$ and $b$, every element is its own inverse. And $b$ must equal $a^{-1}$.

The order of $a$ must be $3$, $4$, or $6$, or else $\langle a\rangle$ has additional generators besides $a$ and $a^{-1}$. But the order of $a$ can't be $4$ given the condition about $4$. And it can't be $6$ or else there are too many elements that are not their own inverses. So the order of $a$ is $3$.

So we have a group with exactly one order-3 cyclic subgroup $\{e,a,a^{-1}\}$, and all other elements have order $2$. Therefore the order of $G$ is $2^n3$. But $4$ doesn't divide $|G|$, so either $|G|=3$ or $|G|=6$. The only possibilities are $C_3$, $C_6$, and $S_3$. But again, $C_6$ has too many elements that are not their own inverses. The other two options check out as meeting the conditions.

Comment: thank you for your nice proof ! I only have one question : Why does every element of $G$ except for $a$ and $b$ have to be its own inverse? I suppose that otherwise they wouldn't generate distinct cyclic subgroups, but I can't see why this is the case.

Comment: It's always true that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ generate the same subgroup. So whenever $g\neq g^{-1}$, you will have two distinct elements generating the same subgroup. That is only allowed to happen in one case here. And for all other $g$, it must be that $g=g^{-1}$.